# Angular App broken after long time and tab need to be refreshed

Tags: angular

I'm facing an odd and complicated issue on my app. I have a website that work perfectly (hosted and deployed with vercel, no subdomains). I always let some tabs of it opened in my browser. And **sometimes** when I go back to my tab, the application shows a blank page (actually not really blank, but my `<app-root>` element is empty.

Here is the error displayed in the console:

```
Failed to load module script: Expected a JavaScript module script but the server responded with a MIME type of "text/html". Strict MIME type checking is enforced for module scripts per HTML spec.
```

When this blank page happen, if I just refresh the page using F5 (or Cmd+R) the application works just fine. So it's not a blocking point to me, it's just really annoying.

Comment: Well, the obvious thing to check is the MIME type that's being sent as the Content-Type header for the script the error is complaining about...

Comment: could that be that you somehow request bundles with old hashes, when new app version is already deployed?

Comment: @Andrei I thought it was because I deployed a new app in the meantime, but I'm not sure I made a deployment between the last time I opened the tab and when I saw this behaviour.

Comment: what "url" try to load?

Comment: @HereticMonkey If the MIME type was actually wrong it would not work after I refresh the page, that's why I never checked it. (Also, I'm not sure on how I could see it, and my 'network' tab on the debugger is empty)

Comment: @Eliseo one with a param -> `https://www.eons-whips.com/fr/simulator/h1.d1d0d29c9c9c423e3e0000006f1928c08422792646..6501234..0c0c0c` which match with the following route : `:lang/simulator/:config`